# Magento(1.9.2.2) static block disappeared

Tags: category, static-block

I need some help about this. I've spent allready 5 hours and have no idea what happened. Problem:
I created a static block ([as described here](http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/display-subcategory-listing-with-the-category-images-in-magento/)) with a simple content, a picture with a link to a product - our christmas product advertising. I placed it as described in a category. This worked as it should. Then We updated magento from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.2, suddenly the static block isnt shown any more. I have no idea what happened and how to bring it back.

there are nop errors in system.log, the block just "disappeared".

We'd be glad for any help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento 1.9.2.2 requires explicit permissions for blocks. See your MAGENTOADMIN/permissions_block/index for current permissions.

Chances are you need to explicitly allow:
`cms/block`
and as per your link
`catalog/navigation`

See this post http://www.dudesquare.nl/blog/2015/10/31/static-block-shortcodes-not-working-1-9-2-2/ to find any other blocks that went missing after the upgrade.

Comment: Man, don't know how to thank you! Exact answer for my problem. And on a sunday. You Sir deserve a beer from me! Give me a message when you're near munich ;)